# Does $\sum_1^\infty \frac{n}{n^2 + 4}$ converge or diverge? Is my solution correct?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Does $\sum_1^\infty \frac{n}{n^2 + 4}$ converge or diverge?

I am confused because my friend insists the series converges conditionally. I think the series diverges. Here is my process and solution:

$\sum_1^\infty \frac{n}{n^2 + 4}$

### Limit Comparison Test:

Let $\sum_1^\infty \frac{n}{n^2 + 4} = \sum_1^\infty a_n$

Let $\sum_1^\infty b_n = \sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{n}$

Since $$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} | \frac{a_n}{b_n}| = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} | \frac{\frac{n}{n^2 + 4}}{\frac{1}{n}}| = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^2}{n^2 + 4} = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^2}{n^2(1 + \frac{4}{n^2})} = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{1 + \frac{4}{n^2}} = 1$$

and $1 > 0$ and $1$ is a finite number,

we can say that the behavior of $\sum_1^\infty a_n$ is the same as the behavior of $\sum_1^\infty b_n$.

Since $\sum_1^\infty b_n$ diverges ( $\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ diverges by p-series, $p=1$), $\sum_1^\infty a_n$ diverges.

So by the Limit Comparison Test, $\sum_1^\infty \frac{n}{n^2 + 4}$  diverges.

Right?

---

Also, this problem was an exercise in the Ratio/Root Test section. Both tests, however seem to fail. Can the convergence be solved with the Root Test or the Ratio Test?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: One can say that it converges improperly to $+\infty$ (and if working in the extended real line, it even converges properly to $+\infty$), and it does that unconditionally.

Comment: Your friend doesn't know what conditional convergence means! Only a series with infinitely many strictly negative terms (and infinitely many strictly positive terms) can be conditionally convergent.

Answer (score 11):

Direct comparison is a little easier here:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{n^2+4} \geq \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n}{n^2+4} \geq \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n}{n^2+n^2} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n} = \infty$$

Comment: So I assume we are allowed to take the sum of the series from $n = 2$ instead of $n = 1$. Also, this problem was an exercise in the Ratio/Root Test section. Both tests, however seem to fail. Can the convergence be solved with the Root Test or the Ratio Test?

Comment: The difference between summing from 1 and from 2 is only one finite term, so the result (convergent or divergent) will not be affected.

Comment: The Ratio Test is inconclusive here, because the ratio of consecutive terms tends to $1$.

Comment: @EWHLee I see. $$Finite + Finite = Finite$$

Comment: @gragas: Yes. But now I updated it so that the argument is more complete.

Comment: Correct. In the cases of series, you are more interested in the existence of a finite value than in the exact numerical answer, because if it is convergent, you can approximate it with finitely many terms. If it is not convergent, you can forget about approximation. Think about series for $\sin x$ or one of the other related transcendental functions ($e^x$ etc).

Answer (score 0):

Write $\frac{n}{n^2 + 4} = \frac1{n + \frac{4}{n}}$. Note that $ n + \frac{4}{n} \le n + 4 $. Use comparison test.

Answer (score 0):

Since your $a_n \geqslant \frac {1} {2n}$ except at $n = 1$ and $\sum \frac {1} {2n}$ diverges, you establish that $\sum a_n$ diverges.